# Jquery animation disappears after several clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing jquery small animation of fade in  to form validation

This is working perfectly fine, but after several clicks the div opacity is changing to its lowest until it totally disappears

Here is my fade in code

```
$("#edit-username check").addClass("right").css("display","none").stop().fadeIn();
```

And here what I do to hide this class effect

```
$("#edit-username #check").removeClass("right");
```

Here is the jsfiddle to my code (the problems appear best on tab click several times) 
http://jsfiddle.net/77BbA/20/
thanks alot in advance

Comment: there is nothing here changing the opacity!

Comment: could u put up your code on jsfiddle ?

Comment: the fade in does change opacity in the inline style

Comment: @Pasty Issa I can but its a part of a long code , so I'm not quite sure if this will be helpful?

Comment: Why do you call the `stop()` function?

Comment: because if you dont, it will do loop animation after several clicks

Comment: Could you post a self-contained example at http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: well i was more concerned about the click function that is triggering this one

Comment: I will post it to jsfiddle then

Comment: @Lamis: you said that tha animation will loop after several click, and that's the reason why ou put the `stop()` function. I'd say that you wrongly bind the click event, in the sense that ou probably add an handler after every click maybe? That's why you need to stop the previous animation...

Comment: @SiGanteng 
here is is the jsfiddle sample...sorry it looks slightly messy just it serves its purpose
http://jsfiddle.net/77BbA/20/

Comment: this especially happens after tab and click

Comment: @themarcuz , I dont know I will try what you said but I doubt it will help ...since I've already run around this before

Comment: Sidenote : instead of `stop()` use `end()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you add extra classes? Try this to show the tag:

`$("#edit-username #check").hide().stop().fadeIn();`

and this to hide:

`$("#edit-username #check").hide();`

In addition you forgot a `#` in front of the first `#check`. You can also use `.animate` for more flexible animations

Comment: extra class because I have wrong and right class ...its ajax check but let me try what you just typed

Comment: $("#edit-username-wrapper #check").addClass("right").css("opacity","0").css("display","block").stop().animate({opacity: 1});

this is working perfectly , thanks